# If I declare(ticks=1) but don't register a tick function, what sort of overhead does the resulting tick processing incur?

Tags: php, c, performance, microbenchmark

First of all - there seem to be many questions about the fundamentals of tick functionality, so I want to add [the top user comment at php.net/declare](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#100137) to the pile for anyone looking for further information. I found it while digging around as I tried to figure out the following.

---

So, I'm working on writing a simple debug helper. I want to add function tracing and benchmarking - basically what tick functionality is perfect for.

Thing is, I want to enable and disable benchmarking depending on arbitrary conditions that occur during script processing. I'm not really looking for fixed debugging à la scoped `declare() { ... }`.

What I'm looking to do is to put `declare();` at the top of my script, and then register and unregister my debugging/benchmarking (tick) function as appropriate. Un/registration won't happen (too) often, so is efficient and reasonable.

But then I got curious: when I don't have a tick function registered... does the fact that I've run `declare(ticks=1);` have any effect on execution efficiency? Does it cause any extra processing to become permanently enabled anyway?

Analysis of PHP(7)'s source code shows that the answer is technically *yes*, but I'm not yet sure *how*.

The answer seems to be in [zend_compile.c:8200](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d3fa900780994ae812b5314900556a7f1bfb916e/Zend/zend_compile.c#L8200): it appears this function defers compilation processing to the appropriate routines, then if ticks are enabled it additionally emits a `ZEND_TICKS` opcode into the opline via `zend_emit_tick()` in [:2167](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d3fa900780994ae812b5314900556a7f1bfb916e/Zend/zend_compile.c#L2167). The [opcode reference page for TICKS](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.ticks.php) seems consistent with this conclusion; it shows an example disassembled opcode listing which has TICKS opcodes scattered throughout it, and I was wondering how they got in there until I discovered the above.

The `ZEND_TICKS` handler (in [zend_vm_def.h:6859](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d56a534acc52b0bb7d61ac7c3386ab96e8ca4a97/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L6859)) seems to call `zend_ticks_function()`. This is mapped to `ticks_function()` in [zend.c:754](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/974a8f8ad2a0ed923abb5c63cfc7d73e2c81e21f/Zend/zend.c#L754), which is in turn mapped to `php_run_ticks()` in [main.2013](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d92a701a3bb99fe8dbaa341589c2fc1e5010a6b8/main/main.c#L2013). *This* is finally defined in [php_ticks.c](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/c8aa6f3a9a3d2c114d0c5e0c9fdd0a465dbb54a5/main/php_ticks.c), where it's all of:

```
void php_run_ticks(int count)
{
  zend_llist_apply_with_argument(
    &PG(tick_functions),
    (llist_apply_with_arg_func_t) php_tick_iterator,
    &count
  );
}
```

Huh. Not bad.

But here's the thing. If I `declare(ticks=1);`, the above dispatch is being run for literally every statement executed. That's... *ouch.* **For long-running scripts containing high-iteration-count, tight processing loops**, I'm wondering how badly that'll add up.

Problem is, I'm not even sure how to benchmark this. The only way I could envisage to do so would be to synthesize some PHP bytecode and then figure out a way to inject that directly into the PHP bytecode interpreter.

And that leads to my question: how much of a performance impact does this additional dispatch have, in practice? How can I quantify it?

Obviously the above investigation was performed on the canonical PHP.net interpreter. I haven't looked into how HHVM does this at all (yet), but I wouldn't at all mind learning how it handles it.

Comment: Sounds like you should bench mark it, but then you would have to write a benchmaker to benchmark your benchmarker.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: Exactly. That's why I was pondering bytecode manipulation. It would eliminate such infinite-recursion issues.

Comment: You lost me at `ticks=1`, sorry.  It's interesting and I wish I knew...  When I bench mark I just time it in micro time, that's my idea of `simple benchmarking`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: it's absolutely fine. I'm leaving this question here knowing it will take a while for it to get answered (and maybe even a mailinglist poke in some weeks or months) because it's very low-level. I'm mostly just academically curious. TL;DR, `declare(ticks=1)` lets you use `register_tick_function()` to register a function that will be run in between every single PHP statement. It was once needed for sane signal handling and some crazy people used it to implement fake exceptions in PHP 4. It's basically a low-level sledgehammer that thankfully has few uses nowadays.

Comment: (By "thankfully has few uses" I mean to say I'm thankful that the things it *very* awkwardly made possible are now doable using canonical, first-class language features (which are actually maintainable to use!).)

Comment: Also, regarding `microtime()` benchmarking, that's how I time things too, because it works so incredibly well for pretty much all intents and purposes. This is the one instance it wouldn't, though, because the `microtime()` calls would be being wrapped by however many TICKS opcodes.

Comment: Right I have read about it but never used it, it's like `goto` one of those curious things I've seen but never really used.  I started using PHP around 5.3, so I messed with some old code that was 4.x mostly updating it etc..  I do understand the principals because `ticks` lets you measure ( like how many cycles it takes etc.. )  I haven't delved much into this low level suff, but I am working on a Tokenizer/Lexer/Parser for, various things.  So I have some idea of the lower level stuff, not much.. but some.

Comment: `goto` has its uses, and is one of those things that are worth learning about so you truly know when it's right to use it. [Here's a fascinating and random PHP-specific one I just found](https://github.com/igorw/retry/issues/3). `ticks` is not itself a measurement mechanism. It simply causes the compiler to inject `TICKS` opcodes into the opline after every single executed statement. That's it. Interesting you mention you're working on tokenzation and parsing! My debug helper library actually parses the PHP source code that calls it to print the names of variables being dumped, etc.

Comment: (cont) That way I can do eg `$x = 1; d($x);` and I'll get `$x: 1` and so forth. I gave up and wrote a parser (only last week, actually) because the old regex-based (!) approach I was using kept failing epically. The task turned out to be refreshingly easy because I'll never see syntactically incorrect code, so I just have to make a parser that won't trip over in ideal circumstances. That said I now want to test it - but that means I need something to compare correctness against. I'm planning on configuring some other (presumably well-tested) tokenizer libraries to do the same thing as (cont)

Comment: my own code, throw Kaltura, TCPDF, etc, at both, and then see if my code fails anywhere. Anyway, now I've explained that - of course I'm very curious: what kind of parsing work have you done? (Sorry this got long, I intended to make it a chat but the link seems to have disappeared. It must only hang around for a little while. Ah well.)

Comment: I'm actually working on lexer tokenizer for an event framework I am creating ( mostly for fun ), Mainly I plan to use it for Events, CSS, HTML, possibly SQL too.  It's more of a shell of a Lexer

Comment: So an example for the event section, my framework creates events for many thing, the request is one of these things, it's based in part off the url.  The events can also contain simple regular expressions or other things.  For example you would "listen" to this event `doRequest/POST|GET/page[0-9]{2}/:any` and my EventLexer would parse that for syntax and create this `^(?:doRequest)\/(?:POST|GET)\/(?:page[0-9]{2})\/(?:[^\/]+)$`  Which works https://regex101.com/r/dLDXV4/1

Comment: If you try doing this for the event `doRequest/POST|GET|/page[0-9]{2}/:any` with an extra PIPE `..GET|/..` You get this `Exception\UnexpectedToken "Expected type 'T_ALPHA' or 'T_NUMBER' given 'T_DELIMETER'"`  The I have it set up it is very powerful and flexible,  https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Evo

Comment: I finally had a chance to take a proper look. That's pretty cool, I think I was able to follow how the code works. Eventing is such an underused concept. My main headscratcher with message-passing is figuring out how to efficiently track hundreds of thousands or even millions of event subscriptions while still being able to use an expressive language. Btw, your `Debug.php` is actually exactly the kind of thing that I'm building at the moment. I'm not sure how long it'll take me to finish it; I'm still working on argument parsing. It'll be the first thing on http://github.com/i336_ haha

Comment: Cool, that (Debug) was one of the first things I built besides the shutdown handler.  My events are chainable, so you could subscript to `doRequest` and it would catch all requests, if you subsribed to that and `doReques/POST` the post one would catch it first and could call `event->stop()`  so I can build routers at any level for requests.  Then like a 404 would be assigned to just requests, and if nothing stops it you get a 404 response etc. but I can do that for any event with a `/` separator.  So the idea is you could have thousands of events, but only hundreds of listeners.

Comment: I'm reworking the Request/Response parts right now to comply with PSR-7 so it's kind of broken...